# Playing audio/video stored in Android assets folder with vlc and fd not working

Tags: android, file-descriptor, libvlc, android-assets

`libvlc` has support to accept a file descriptor as a valid piece of media. `AssetManager` allows you to grab an asset as a file descriptor. If I feed the assets file descriptor to `libvlc`, nothing plays and it stops immediately after attempting to play from the file descriptor. Is there a reason this doesn't work like this?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the reason is that the fd given by any `AssetManager` asset is actually the fd for the whole application package. It is expected that you seek to the place given by `getStartOffset`. Looks like I need to find a way to inform libvlc about this.